# UIButton frame size is always zero

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't get the right dimensions of a UIButton created in my

`- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil`

function:

```
callerPlayerBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[callerPlayerBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"callPlayerBtn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:callerPlayerBtn];   
NSLog(@"SIZES ARE %f %f", callerPlayerBtn.bounds.size.width, callerPlayerBtn.bounds.size.height);
```

What am I doing wrong? The logs are always `0`. I would like to access its dimension to center it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set frame of your button like this:

```
UIButton * callerPlayerBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
callerPlayerBtn.frame = CGRectMake(60, 10, 220, 25); //here we are setting frame
[callerPlayerBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"callPlayerBtn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:callerPlayerBtn];
NSLog(@"SIZES ARE %f %f", callerPlayerBtn.bounds.size.width, callerPlayerBtn.bounds.size.height);
```

Log value will be :

```
2013-03-12 20:02:30.394 SampleProject[591:16a03] SIZES ARE 220.000000 25.000000
```

Answer (score 5):

I see you are creating your button with `buttonWithType:` method and not with nib.

If you do so you need to set the frame your self.

```
callerPlayerBtn.frame = CGRectMake(originx, originy, width, height);
```

for width and height you can use the size of the image for button.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the frame of button also equal to the image width & height if you want the button to be equal in size to the image or you could set the custom custom size  also

```
[callerPlayerBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,buttonImage.size.width,buttonImage.size.height)];
```